# Issue implementing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration

At least, I think that's what the problem is...
I'm trying to create a page where a substring is sent via a query string, and members of a given array that match the substring are displayed on the page.  I know the *logic* in my model works, but obviously something's not going right, because when I send a substring that matches several members of the array, it's returning with "no matches".  I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the model, or the migration.

Here's the model:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
def State.filter(matching_string)

    matcher = Regexp.new(matching_string, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
    @new_array = []
    State.select{|x| if matcher =~ x then @new_array << x end}
    return @new_array

end
end
```

Here's the migration:

```
class CreateStates < ActiveRecord::Migration


 def self.up

  list_of_states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California",
    "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia",
    "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa",
    "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland",
    "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri",
    "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey",
    "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio",
    "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina",
    "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont",
    "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]


    create_table :states do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.timestamps
    end
    State.reset_column_information
    for x in list_of_states
            State.create(:name => x)

    end
     State.all.collect {|x| x.name}
  end



  def self.down
    drop_table :states
  end
end
```

And here's the controller:

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
def filter
    @states = State.filter(params[:substring])
    @entered_string = params[:substring]
end end
```

TIA!

Comment: please provide `params[:substring]` sample

Comment: For example, the end of the url would be ?substring="la", which obviously matches with Alabama, Alaska, and a bunch of other strings, but I'm still receiving "no matches"

Comment: As a note you should never use models in your migrations. At some point in the future you may not even have a State model at which point this migration would be invalid and not run. It is much better, although more annoying, to insert the data directly using `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're experiencing is due to the mis-use of the `select` method. The ActiveRecord::Base implementation is used to select particular columns. You're passing a block to a method that doesn't want one so it is ignored. The net result is nothing.

There are several conventions in Ruby that will make this sort of misbehavior more obvious and easier to fix. For instance, this is how the method would have been written if done according to Ruby conventions:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.filter(matching_string)
    pattern = Regexp.new(matching_string, Regexp::IGNORECASE)

    State.select{ |state| state.name.match(pattern) }
  end
end
```

You would find that the result of this method is always `nil`, so something isn't right. What you actually want is more like this:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.filter(matching_string)
    pattern = Regexp.new(matching_string, Regexp::IGNORECASE)

    @states ||= State.all
    @states.select{ |state| state.name.match(pattern) }
  end
end
```

This presumes that you're not adding and removing states between restarts of the application. This is a fairly safe assumption if dealing with US-only data, especially since your data is loaded in via migrations and does not appear to be user-editable.

You can also simply search the database using the `LIKE` operator:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.filter(matching_string)
    State.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{matching_string}%")
  end
end
```

The first method works better for small lists of states, the latter for larger lists. In this case "large" means 1000+.